# SQL database value to variable

Tags: php, sql, session, pdo

So, I am kinda new to php and mysql, but I have found a login form and adapted it to my needs as I dont have the knowledge to make one my self yet. I added a firstname and surname column into the database and the register form adds the values into the database fine.

Now I want to be able to display the firstname and surname onto a restricted page, the reason why I need this is because I want it to say: Welcome Jo Blogs. Below is the register form.

```
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['surname'])):

    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, surname) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :surname)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $_POST['surname']);

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    else:
        $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
    endif;

endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <?php include '../header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <span>or <a href="login.php">login here</a></span>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm_password">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="firstname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" name="surname">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And below here is the login form as im not really sure what you guys need to help me :)

```
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email,password FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        header("Location: /");

    } else {
        $message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
    }

endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <?php include '../header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
    <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h1>Login</h1>
    <span>or <a href="register.php">register here</a></span>

    <form action="login.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Also while I am here, I am currently using javascript to redirect to the homepage once you log out as i couldn't find any information on how to do it with php

Restricted.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restricted Area</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php
    include '../header.php';
    ?>

</head>
<body>

    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ?>
        <h1>Restriced Area</h1>

        <h2>You have sucessfully logged in with your credentials</h2>
    <?php
    } else { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "login.php";
        </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }

    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Just let me know if you guys need any more information/code.

Thanks.

Comment: `echo $username` will print to screen?

Comment: the username is there email, i would like it if it was there name got displayed.

Comment: displayed where exactly? In the last bit of code? well no matter.. as soon as you have your first and surname just add them to your session and display them wherever you like..

Comment: Inside your `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {` in the last piece of code, run a query, `SELECT CONCAT(firstname, " ", surname) as name FROM users WHERE id=:id` and fetch that value. Should give you what you need. Then use `$row['name']` (where `$row` is the fetched array) and it gives it directly. Use your `$_SESSION['user_id']` variable to bind for `:id`

Comment: yes, restricted.php (i edited it) in the part with the "<h1> restricted area</h1>"

Comment: @Qirel you should have posted that or requested by the OP to post that as an answer; IMHO.

Comment: btw; you're most likely outputting before header in your "Restricted.php" file, and error reporting would have thrown you something about it.

Comment: @Qirel then again; maybe not. seeing they're having trouble with an answer given. So, strike my comment ;-)

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));` you should be getting an error about this, but you're not checking for them.

Comment: Went alt-tab for a bit, seems like OP got his solution anyway ;-) Albeit, not one I'd prefer! @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Quirel i would have gone with the one that you suggested, but its not working, nothing inside of the if statment shows up. If it works then id rather use this one

Comment: looked to bad... http://pastebin.com/mJHGpq1P

Comment: it gives the error of #0 {main}
  thrown in /dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/restricted.php on line 21 (removed directory names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Qirel suggested...

Restricted.php should resemble this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: /login.php");  // no need to query
}
require('database.php');  // assumed to declare $conn=new PDO(...);
$loggedin = $conn->prepare('SELECT firstname,surname FROM users WHERE id=?');
$loggedin->execute([$_SESSION['user_id']]);
$results = $loggedin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!$results) {
    header("Location: /login.php");  // unsuccessful query
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restricted Area</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php include '../header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Restriced Area</h1>
    <h2>You have successfully logged in with your credentials</h2>
    <?php echo "Welcome {$results['firstname']} {$results['surname']}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edit:

This statement borders on *too serious* but I would like to mention, especially to inexperienced php coders, that SESSION data can be hijacked (this is outlined in **Pro PHP Security: From Application Security Principles to the Implementation of XSS Defense - Chapter 7: Preventing Session Hijacking**) and so it can be suggested to never store any personal information in $_SESSION.  This would most critically include <kbd>credit card numbers</kbd>, <kbd>government issued ids</kbd>, and <kbd>passwords</kbd>; but would also extend into less assuming data like <kbd>usernames</kbd>, <kbd>emails</kbd>, <kbd>phone numbers</kbd>, etc which would allow a hacker to impersonate/compromise a legitimate user.

The internet is still very much in its "Wild West" era, and nothing is 100% safe.  ...and Internet Security is a rabbit hole / money pit.  Every coder should devote some time to understanding known threats and preventing them, but just how far to go with this will differ from person to person.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /***/*****l/******/*****/register.php on line 22  | line 22 is the "$loggedin->execute();"

Comment: So all i need to do is paste this into the restricted.php instead of the other if else statment and it should work? @mickmackusa

Comment: Thats a fair point, i guess its better to start learning things the "correct way". So ive tried your solution, and the page is just showing up blank, so im guessing that theres something up with the if statment. Here is the error that im getting: [18-Mar-2017 12:31:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in dirremoved/restricted.php:18     and    #0 {main}
  thrown in dirremoved/restricted.php on line 18

Comment: when i do: echo "Test " . $_SESSION["user_id"] ;   it displays Test 22 on the page (with 22 being the id in the database.) with this being the if else statment that runs: http://pastebin.com/bK6wmXgN

Comment: theres no change in the appearance with the page, or the errors which are in the error log, Stack trace: #0 {main}
  thrown in directoryremoved/restricted.php on line 18

Comment: still no change and the same errors with adding the PDO::PARAM_INT on the end

Comment: Yes it is in the first line of the file.

Comment: yes putting SELECT firstname,surname FROM users WHERE id=22 into the database returns the record, so it would need to look like this: http://pastebin.com/T2k9GPSG

Comment: still not outputing anything onto the page

Comment: yes, still with the same error. Im heading off for the night now so i will have a look at what you send when i wake up.

Comment: @Jeff I have done a full rewrite of the Restricted.php file so hopefully any typos or missing db connections will be corrected.  I have tested this on my server and it works with a $_SESSION variable that points to an existing row in my database.  If you are still having trouble, then there may be something external fouling things up that I may or may not be able to assist with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this??

In the first snippet after successfully adding a new user..

```
if( $stmt->execute() ):
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];
    # redirect to login or you could just 
    # have the logged in at this point and..
    # redirect to restricted.php..
    header("Location: /login.php");
else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
endif;
```

Then set up restricted.php like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: /login.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restricted Area</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php include '../header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $_SESSION['surname']; ?></h1>
<h2>You have sucessfully logged in with your credentials</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have decided to go with the other one as it means that im not storing peoples names etc in the session, thanks for the solution anyway