# Integrating Codeigniter 3 with phpmyadmin database and fullcalendar.io

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Hello im using fullcalendar.io for my website, for the framework i use ci3, im new with ci.
So the problem is, can i just load the database fullcalendar.io just for user who logged in?
im planning to use email to connect it since i used email to login to my website..

here is my user database example :
[image]

here is my events on fullcalendar.io database :

[image]

here is my load function in controllers

```
 function load()
    {

        $event_data = $this->fullcalendar_model->fetch_all_event();
        foreach ($event_data->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'title' => $row['title'],
                'start' => $row['start_event'],
                'end' => $row['end_event']
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and here is my fetch_all_event() code

```
function fetch_all_event()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id');
        return $this->db->get_where('events');
    }
```

should i adding something or what? can anyone help please im just starting with ci, thank u

Comment: "can i just load the database fullcalendar.io just for user who logged in"...yes you can. You just need to add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL query and pass in the email address of the current user. (I am assuming you store the email and/or user ID in the Session when the user is logged in, which is the normal way.). Unfortunately since you didn't share the code from your `fetch_all_event()` function, I can't give you any more specific advice than that.

Comment: already edited, i put the basic fetch_all_event code, hope it can help u for give me more specific advice? @ADyson

Comment: Well I don't know codeigniter very much I'm afraid.  But the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) has what looks to me like a very clear example of how you pass data into a `get_where` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easiest way is you just have to store ur session data when u log in, store it at the page u login at.
here is mine :

```
if ($user) {
            // jika usernya ada
            if ($user['is_active'] == 1) {
                if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
                    $data = [
                        'email' => $user['email'],
                        'role_id' => $user['role_id']
                    ];
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

and u can call that email in ur load model, here is my fetch_all_event function code on my model :

```
function fetch_all_event()
    {
        $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $this->db->order_by('id');
        return $this->db->get_where('events', ['email' => $email]);
    }
```

this will solve that problem, kept that in mind ur email at database shouldnt do as primary or unique key.

Comment: I will recommend that you not store identifiable data in your session.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42869960/2943403